# update-rc.d subversion default command not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, startup

I have ubuntu 18.04 bionic server.

I Install the subversion. Running subversion manually without problems

Manual start command `svnserve -d -r /srv/svnrepos/it/`

What should I do to run automatically at system startup.

I did these, but it did not

`cd /etc/init.d/`

`touch svnserve`

`vi /etc/init.d/svnserve`

svnserve file content 
   `svnserve -d -r /srv/svnrepos/it/`

`update-rc.d svnserve defaults`

but I could not run `update-rc.d`

Comment: AFAIK you shouldn't be using SysV init scripts anymore - you may find this helpful: [how to start svnserve with systemctl systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584047/4440445)

Answer (score 0):

```
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides: 3Proxy
   # Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
   # Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
   # Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
   # Short-Description: Initialize 3proxy server
   # Description: starts 3proxy
   ### END INIT INFO
```

Answer (score -1):

In order for `update-rc.d` to work correctly, you need to add a section to svnserve::

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: svnserve
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Initialize svnserve
# Description: starts svnserve
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: пожалуйста, пиши по-английски.